# double quotes in string representation

Tags: python, python-2.7

This snippet:

```
formatter = "%r %r %r %r"
print formatter % (
    "I had this thing.",
    "That you could type up right.",
    "But it didn't sing.",
    "So I said goodnight."
)
```

when run, prints this string:

```
'I had this thing.' 'That you could type up right.' "But it didn't sing." 'So I said goodnight.'
```

Why did `"But it didn't sing."` get put in double quotes when the other three items were in single quotes?

(This code is taken from [Learn Python the Hard Way Exercise 8](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex8.html).)

Comment: Look at the word "didn't" --> it contains a single quote.

Comment: Because that is the only one string that has a single quote inside it. So, it is not possible a string like `'But it didn't sing'`.

Comment: but why does python do that? =o. Is there a reason for it?

Comment: Since the original string contains a single quote, Python is adding double-quotes around the string to make it *unambiguous.*  In other words, with double quotes around the whole string, there is no possibility of the `'` being mis-interpreted as the beginning or end of another string.

Comment: Recall that you used the `%r` formatter, which theoretically should print out valid Python code for creating a new object (which is true for all of Python's built-in data types).

Comment: Why is this too localized? It is simply giving a reproducible example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python is clever; it'll use double quotes for strings that contain single quotes when generating the representation, to minimize escapes:

```
>>> 'no quotes'
'no quotes'
>>> 'one quote: \''
"one quote: '"
```

Add a double quote in there *as well* and it'll revert back to single quotes and escape any single quotes contained:

```
>>> 'two quotes: \'\"'
'two quotes: \'"'
```

Comment: +1 but would be better if it explained the repr() / str() distinction